# How do you append an array of keys to object?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings and a params object like this. How do I create the params constant? Using either forEach, map, and or filter?

```
key = ['dog', 'car', 'cat'];
value = [ 3, 1, 2 ];

    const params = {
       item: {
           [key]: value[0],
           // more keys to be appended
       }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want your result to be?

Comment: `[key]` doesn't work with an array. You need to write it out as `{[key[0]]: value[0], [key[1]]: value[1], …}`. Or yes, just use a loop and assign properties dynamically starting from an empty object.

Comment: The params to be generated without manually entering in each key value pair. The reason I'm doing it is because sometimes my key value pair may be several dozen and I want it to be created on the fly depending on how many are there. I'm trying to insert it into a database so I have columns generated depending on how many properties there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looping through each value:

```js
const key = ['dog', 'car', 'cat'];
const value = [ 3, 1, 2 ];

const item = {};
key.forEach((k, i) => { item[k] = value[i]; });

const parmas = {};
parmas.item = item;
console.log(parmas);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an object's keys using the following syntax:

```
obj[key] = value
```

So in you case, you could do something like:

```
key = ['dog', 'car', 'cat'];
value = [ 3, 1, 2 ];

var params = {
    item : {}
}

for (var i=0; i<key.length;i++){
    params.item[key[i]] = value[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
value.reduce((acc, val, index) => (acc[key[index]] = val, acc), {});
```

This produces:

{dog: 3, car: 1, cat: 2}